# How can I toggle ng-show to display field that is hidden?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to figure out how to approach this problem without using JQuery so any help would be appreciated.

Basically I'm calling a rest service that displays customer data on fields in the screen.  The database has 4 Address Lines that it returns.  The first address line is a required field but the rest are optional.

Using ng-show I have managed to only show the address lines that have data on load of the page, but I would like to use a bootstrap plus sign at the end of each line to force the next address line to show if blank.  That way if the user needs to add to the address he or she can.

What would be the best approach for this?  Here's my code so far:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="AddressLine1" placeholder ="Address Line" ng-model="order.joAddressLine1" required />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="AddressLine2" placeholder ="Address Line" ng-model="order.joAddressLine2" ng-show="order.joAddressLine2" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="AddressLine3" placeholder ="Address Line" ng-model="order.joAddressLine3" ng-show="order.joAddressLine3" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="AddressLine4" placeholder ="Address Line" ng-model="order.joAddressLine4" ng-show="order.joAddressLine4" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="City" placeholder ="City" ng-model="order.joCity" required />
```

Comment: a fiddle or at least your directive would help to clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: you need a separate property for each line that can be toggled true or false;  what you are doing right now is showing an input if the model isn't `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/118bfzfp/

Html

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="AddressLine1" placeholder ="Address Line" ng-model="order.joAddressLine1" required />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="AddressLine2" placeholder ="Address Line" ng-model="order.joAddressLine2" ng-show="order.joAddressLine2 || show2" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="AddressLine3" placeholder ="Address Line" ng-model="order.joAddressLine3" ng-show="order.joAddressLine3 || show3" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="AddressLine4" placeholder ="Address Line" ng-model="order.joAddressLine4" ng-show="order.joAddressLine4 || show4" />
    <button ng-click="add()">+</button>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="City" placeholder ="City" ng-model="order.joCity" required />
</div>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('test',[]).controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.order = {
        joAddressLine1: 'sample'
    };

    $scope.add = function () {
        $scope.show2 = true;
        $scope.show3 = $scope.order.joAddressLine2;
        $scope.show4 = $scope.order.joAddressLine3;
    }    
});
```

Comment: awesome, I didnt realize I could have conditional statements in ng-show.  Still getting used to AngularJS. Thanks